# Test Retest reliability with different rater numbers

Tags: reliability, intraclass-correlation, cohens-kappa

I was wondering whether its possible to run a test-retest reliability analysis, but with a different number of raters for the two time points.

I have collected personality data and am looking at stability over time. For time 1 (T1), I have personality ratings for the participants from 17 raters. For T2 (10 years later), I have personality ratings for the participants from 21 raters. Is it possible to run a test-retest reliability analysis with different rater numbers at the two time points, or do I need to use the same (i.e. 17 raters)? Additionally, if I use the same number of raters, how do I select with 17 of the T2 22 raters to chose? The ones with the most reliable scores?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the personality ratings?

Comment: Yes, of course. They are personality ratings for animals. The instrument is a 41 item questionnaire, loosely based on the human Big Five (the version I am using has six overall traits). Carestaff completed the questionnaire for the animals in 2007, and (mostly different) carestaff again completed the questionnaires in 2017. Is that enough information, or is there anything else that would help?